# How to extract data from the first line and put into the attribute in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to extract data and put it into the attribute.
For example data:

```
001ABC
UP1XYZ   00012564789
99120210101999999999
```

I want only the ABC in the first line for putting into the attribute. This ABC can be any string with 3 to 4 characters. I am not sure how can I get it?

My flow would be: GetFile -> SplitText -> ExrtactText -> UpdateAttribute -> RouteText
I think before splitting the text, should I put any processor to get ABC?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new property to ExtractText as `first_line = \A(.*)$`, this will create a new `first_line` attribute, and you can further process it accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, it did not work. I got the attribute value as 99120210101999999999 for first_line, first_line.0, and first_line.1

Comment: try this `\A.*`

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde what processor is that you are suggesting to use?

Comment: @edjm - `ExtractText`